# Trying to get this simple Jquery.parseJson to work without success

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I'm trying to get this Jquery.parseJson to work without success.

```
<input type="text" id="query" /><button>search</button><br />
<div id="results">

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
  $("#query").val(); // Do nothing with this value
  $.getJSON('{"name":"John"}',function(json){
   $.each(json.results,function(i,obj){
      $("#results").append('<p>' + obj.name + '</p>');
   });
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

What this code is meant to do is to show the name "John" in the div results.

Can someone give me some clues about what I'm doing wrong?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "eval" to transform strings into JSON objects.
Keep in mind that the strings needs to be bracketed not to be recognized as a Labeled Statement.

```
    <input type="text" id="query" /><button>search</button><br />
    <div id="results">

    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('button').click(function(){
                $("#query").val(); // Do nothing with this value
                var json = eval('({"name":"John"})');
                $("#results").append('<p>' + json.name + '</p>');
                // $.getJSON('{"name":"John"}',function(json){
                //     $.each(json.results,function(i,obj){
                //         $("#results").append('<p>' + obj.name + '</p>');
                //     });
                // });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

[`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) is for fetching JSON *from a URL*, you just want [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) when operating on a string you already have, like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $("#query").val(); // Do nothing with this value
  var obj = $.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
  $("#results").append('<p>' + obj.name + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But it is not working. I have used firebug and I get the variable obj allways undefined.

Comment: parseJSON was added in jQuery 1.4.1 and he's using 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug to check if you pass in the each statements.

Then inspect json